# PHP - Encaminhar $_POST para outro domínio

Tags: php, post

Olá, pessoal

Eu tenho a seguinte página: "xxx.com.br/pagina1.php"

Nessa pagina1.php contém um formulário cujo "action" está setado para "yyy.com.br/pagina2.php" (outro domínio)

Eu estou conseguindo receber as variáveis $_POST do formulario normalmente pela pagina2 do outro dominio... Mas preciso encaminhar uma dessas variáveis para "xxx.com.br/pagina3.php" (uma terceira página do dominio anterior)

Estou tendo dificuldade para encaminhar um $_POST recebido para uma outra página de outro domínio... Como faço isso?

Comment: Usa `cUrl` na pagina2 para enviar para pagina3.

Comment: Usarei o cUrl com o exemplo do amigo ali, obrigado!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quando você recuperar o segundo `POST`, utilize o `cURL` para enviar os dados que tem via `POST` para outro lugar.

```
<?php
# instancia
$ch = curl_init();
# aqui você transforma seu POST
# você pode fazer um tratamento das variáveis aqui
$meuPost = http_build_query($_POST);
# aqui você informa a url da próxima página
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"xxx.com.br/pagina3.php");
# aqui você define que é envio via POST
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
# aqui você pega os dados do post que tinha e reenvia eles
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $meuPost);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
# mostra o que aconteceu
print_r($server_output);
```

Comment: Eu preciso tratar os dados na pagina2, encaminhar um dos $_POST para a pagina3 e logo em seguida, redirecionar para a pagina3 com o $_POST carregado... Eu coloco essas linhas logo após o tratamento dos dados?

Comment: Sim. Se usar o exemplo que passei, faça o tratamento do seu `post` como necessita, depois passe os dados para a variável `$meuPost` para acontecer o tratamento delas no formado que o `cURL` nesse exemplo está usando para aí sim enviar os dados para lá.

Comment: Certo, tentarei fazer assim... Muito obrigado!

Comment: Só mais uma dúvida... Como o "print_r" funcionaria sendo que a página vai ser redirecionada e não vai dar tempo de printar o output?

Comment: Não vai ser redirecionado querido, ele vai simular que redirecionou para a página 3, enviar os dados e ficar no mesmo lugar. O `print_r` eu coloquei ali só para você ter certeza do que tá acontecendo com a execução.

Comment: Mas eu realmente precisava que ele redirecionasse e carregasse a página3.php com o $_POST enviado pela pagina2

Comment: Opá, dá uma olhada nesse post então: [PHP Redirect with POST data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576619/php-redirect-with-post-data). Mas você pode executar o `cURL` e em seguida, após a execução redirecionar para a página. Aí vai depender de como você tá estruturando a aplicação.

Comment: Essa outra pergunta era exatamente o que eu precisava. Então eu posso usar:

'<form action='xxx.com.br/pagina3.php' method='post' name='frm'>
<?php
$meuPost = $_POST['campoA'];
?>
<input type='hidden' name="campoA" value="<?php echo "$meuPost";?>"/>;

</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.frm.submit();
</script>'

Isso criaria um formulario com hidden inputs e logo depois daria um submit para a pagina3.php, né?

Comment: Opá ! Exatamente isso. (obs. eu acho isso gambiarra kkk)

Comment: Kkkkk sem problemas, estou fazendo esse "balão" para outro domínio por motivos de "não confio no cara q tem acesso ao banco de dados do primeiro domínio e estou tratando os dados no banco de dados do segundo domínio que ele nem sabe que existe"... Agradeço muito pela ajuda!

Comment: Opá, estamos aí pra isso. Um abraço.